# How can I pass a Python parameter in config.py to .sql file?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Python Snowflake connector to extract data from tables in Snowflake. Here is my file structure:

```
sql
   a.sql
   b.sql
   c.sql
configurations.py
data_extract.py
main.py
```

Here the sql folder contains all my sql queries in .sql files. I put these sql files separately because they are handreds of lines long each and looks messy if I put them into python files.
*configuration.py* contains datetime parameters I want to change every time I run the code. It looks like this:

```
START_TIME = '2018-10-01 00:00:00'
END_TIME = '2019-04-01 00:00:00'
```

I want to add these parameters into the .sql files. For example, *a.sql* includes the following content:

```
DECLARE
  @START_PICKUP_DATE DATE,
  @END_PICKUP_DATE DATE,

SET
  @START_PICKUP_DATE = '2018-10-01'

SET
  @END_PICKUP_DATE = '2019-04-01'

select supplier_confirmation_id, pickup_datetime, dropoff_datetime, pickup_station_distance
from SANDBOX.ZQIAN.V_PDL
where pickup_datetime >= START_PICKUP_DATE and pickup_datetime < END_PICKUP_DATE
      and supplier_confirmation_id is not null;
```

I use *a.sql* in my python code in the following way:

```
def executeSQLScriptsFromFile(filepath):
    # snowflake credentials, replace SECRET with your own
    ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user='S_ANALYTICS_USER',
        account=SECRET_A,
        region='us-east-1',
        warehouse=SECRET_B,
        database=SECRET_C,
        role=SECRET_D,
        password=SECRET_E)

    fd = open(filepath, 'r')
    query = fd.read()
    fd.close()

    cs = ctx.cursor()
    try:
        cur = cs.execute(query)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(iter(cur), columns=[x[0] for x in cur.description])
    finally:
        cs.close()
    ctx.close()

    return df

def extract_data():
    a_sqlpath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sql\a.sql')
    a_df = executeSQLScriptsFromFile(a_sqlpath)
    return a_df
```

**The problem is I want START_PICKUP_DATE and END_PICKUP_DATE in a.sql file to be synced and equal to START_TIME and END_TIME in configurations.py file so that I only need to change START_TIME and END_TIME in configurations.py and extract data in different timeframe using a.sql in Snowflake.**

I've been looking for solutions online for quite a long time, but still not able to find a good solution that is specific to my problem. Many thanks to anyone who can provide a hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to parameterize the sql statements so that instead of declaring in the SQL file you can just make it a parameter passed during execution.

```
select supplier_confirmation_id, pickup_datetime, dropoff_datetime, pickup_station_distance
from SANDBOX.ZQIAN.V_PDL
where pickup_datetime >= %(START_PICKUP_DATE)s and pickup_datetime < %(END_PICKUP_DATE)s and supplier_confirmation_id is not null;
```

Then when calling the function, just send the parameters `START_PICKUP_DATE` and `END_PICKUP_DATE` as parameters to the execute statement.  One way to do this is to do a mapping from the parameter name to the value of the parameter.  (In this example I'm assuming you have a function that will get the parameter value).

```
cur = cs.execute(query, {'START_PICKUP_DATE':get_value_from_config('start_pickup'), 'END_PICKUP_DATE':get_value_from_config('end_pickup')})
```

Or you can pass them by location

```
cur = cs.execute(query, [get_value_from_config('start_pickup'), get_value_from_config('end_pickup')])
```

Which in essense becomes

```
cur = cs.execute(query, ['2018-10-01 00:00:00','2019-04-01 00:00:00'])
```

Comment: @MichaeID Thanks for the suggestion! What if the parameter name in configurations.py and in a.sql are not exactly the same?

Comment: @MichaelID, BTW, do you have any documentation where I can refer to? For example, how can I activate get_value_from_config() ?

Comment: I just used the made up function called `get_value_from_config` that you can create.  Nothing special about it at all.  The key is that you are passing the parameters as part of the execute statement.  I'll update answer with some more details

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#paramstyle and https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#execute

Comment: Thanks! Slight modification by adding 's' after '%(param_name)', ending up in  '%(param_name)s'. See below:  ```select supplier_confirmation_id, pickup_datetime, dropoff_datetime, pickup_station_distance
from SANDBOX.ZQIAN.V_PDL
where pickup_datetime >= %(START_PICKUP_DATE)s and pickup_datetime < %(END_PICKUP_DATE)s
      and supplier_confirmation_id is not null;```

Comment: @MichaeID, I tried the method you provided and it works well except in one occasion it keeps giving me the following error: ```query = command % processed_params
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
``` It seems ```cs.execute(query, param_dict)``` is not recognizing the parameters somehow. The only difference I observed is I used 'With' in my sql query and the parameters are in the child queries. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, I would take your .sql files and extract the queries into triple-quoted python strings with format specifiers for your variables. Then import the queries into your main script just like you import your configuration:

```
sql_queries.py:

sql_a = """
DECLARE
  @START_PICKUP_DATE DATE,
  @END_PICKUP_DATE DATE,

SET
  @START_PICKUP_DATE = {START_TIME}

SET
  @END_PICKUP_DATE = {END_TIME}

select supplier_confirmation_id, pickup_datetime, dropoff_datetime, pickup_station_distance
from SANDBOX.ZQIAN.V_PDL
where pickup_datetime >= START_PICKUP_DATE and pickup_datetime < END_PICKUP_DATE
  and supplier_confirmation_id is not null;
"""

main:
from sql_queries import sql_a

print(sql_a.format(configuration.START_TIME, configuration.END_TIME))
```